# How do I display search results in the header of new page linked to result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search box and results, when I click the result and directed to a specific page I want the result to show at the header of directed page with php.

This is the result page:

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user="a";
$pass="a";
$db="pax";
mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
mysql_select_db($db);


$button = $_GET['submit'];
$search = $_GET['search'];

if (!$button)
 echo "you didn't submit a keywoard";
else
{
   if (strlen($search)<=2)
       echo " Search term too short";
   else 
   {
       echo " you searched for $search<hr size='1'>";
   }
}
$sql="select * from names where names like '%$search%'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){

echo '<a href=directedpage.php </a>'. "<br>".$row['names'];
}

?>
```

Comment: `'$pass="a";` is this a mistake because to me this looks like it'll throw a syntax error

Comment: thanks .. yes this mistake during post writing

Comment: You really should not be writing code that relies on mysql_ functions anymore. The MySQL extension has been deprecated for years and is about to be dropped in the upcoming PHP7 release. Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: then what is the alternative way . iam newer member in programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

You have a few syntax errors in the HTML that is echoed so I've simplified.
The directedpage.php will need to receive the search term and put it in the appropriate place.

Example:
From your code-

```
echo '<a href=directedpage.php?searchTerm='.$search.'>Click Here</a>';
```

An abbreviated directedpage.php-

```
echo '<html><head><title>'.$_POST['searchTerm'].'</title></head>';
....
```

This can be expanded upon sending all sorts of analytical data to the "directedpage.php" using any method you see fit.

Comment: thanks for your answer.. i am not understand of $_POST['seachterm']

Comment: By appending a '?' mark to the end of the URL in your results, i.e. `<a href="directedpage.php?searchTerm='.$search.'">` you are sending the directedpage.php variables using POST which are held in an array _POST. These are accessed using the key that you dictate in the URL; so the variable `_POST['searchterm']` will store what ever is passed in the URL. If this is above your skill level you should check out a tutorial on form processing with PHP.